# Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to write a dart program which can register users and upon error print its description which i will eventually use in a Toast but it gives an error on catchError

```
User? _user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                  email: email.toString(),
                                  password: password.toString())
                              .catchError((e) {
                        print(e.message);
                        
                      })).user;
```

> I/flutter ( 3113): The email address is already in use by another account.
> E/flutter ( 3113): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type
> E/flutter ( 3113): #0      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:181:7)
> E/flutter ( 3113): #1      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:778:47)
> E/flutter ( 3113): #2      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:799:13)
> E/flutter ( 3113): #3      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:574:5)
> E/flutter ( 3113): #4      _completeOnAsyncError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:287:13)
> E/flutter ( 3113): #5      FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart)
> E/flutter ( 3113): 
> E/flutter ( 3113):

Comment: just return something, i.e. null or empty string, anything, inside catchError , basically when your code catch error, you are printing but not return anything, but your createUser...() method is still expecting something

/////// sample code:
    YourResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email.toString(),
      password: password.toString(),
    ).catchError((e) {
      print(e.message);
      return null;
    });

       User? _user = result?.user;

Comment: but then if you put empty string , your "user" is gonna throw another error , about string does not contain user

Comment: using `then` is another way without `await`, u retrieve user inside `then()`
///////////////sample:
`User? user=null;
_auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
email: email.toString(),
password: password.toString()
).then((result) {result.user})
  .catchError((e) {
     print(e.message);
  })`

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping it in a `try...catch` bloc it will throw `FirebaseAuthException` with a `message` field containing your message

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/error-handling/

Comment: yeah that works but i wanted to use `catchError()`

Comment: @UsamaFayyaz Why?  Using `await` with `try`-`catch` is the same thing but is *much* less confusing and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Split it up like so:

```
await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: email.toString(),
  password: password.toString(),
).catchError((e) {
  print(e.message);
});
User? user = _auth.currentUser;
```

Comment: It is still throwing the same exception

`Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type`

Comment: The error message is telling you to look at the type which is returned from `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` - whatever type that is, you need to return it in your catchError block. But anyway, I would agree with other commenters - you should use try / catch instead. Mixing await and catchError is always going to get messy